# How to configure MVC3 localization of Account LogOn?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization

I recently switched my mvc3 localization structure from lang as subdomain (fr.domain.com) to lang as path (domain.com/fr).

Everything works fine but the automatic redirection to account logon.

Let's say I'm not authenticated and I try to access domain.com/fr/test I'm redirected to domain.com/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl...

How can I configure my site so that I get redirected to /fr/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl...

edit :

I use route mapping

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "DefaultLocalized", // Route name
        "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { lang = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        , new { lang = "fr" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

SOLUTION :
Here is my solution implementation based on developer10214's suggestion

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query.Contains("%2ffr%2f") && System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName != "fr")
                return Redirect("/fr/Account/LogOn" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query);

            LogOnModel model = new LogOnModel() { UserName = "", Password = "" };
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: It would be useful to know how you made the change for your localization (route mapping, areas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason why you get redirected to the common account/logon action is, that this path is configured in your memebership section in your web.config. Every request for an action which is protected by the Authorize attribute will end up there, if you are not logged in.

A possible solution could be:

- change the logon action, by extracting lang parameter from the return url and redirect to the correct logon action